# MyISAM & InnoDB alternatives

Tags: mysql

i have a table - User profile (currently use MYISAM)

I have search bar can search this table - name, email, current city.(I use FULLTEXT SEARCH)

However in this table will be lots of **update** and **optional field**(NULL default)

If I use INNODB, I will have to switch to `%LIKE%`
If I use LIKE, i wrote a code like this

I break string into array than use LIKE to search

```
$nums=//count(array());
for($n=0; $n<$nums; $n++){  
    $SQL .="
     (
     fullname LIKE :search_1_$n OR 
     email LIKE :search_2_$n OR 
     city LIKE :search_3_$n
     ) && //remove last && after
   ";
}
```

SELECT...WHERE $statement...

**MyISAM:**

```
Good - FULLTEXT serach, search speed
Bad - UPDATE, NULL take more space
```

**InnoDB:**

```
Good - UPDATE, NULL
BAD - no FULLTEXT SEARCH, search speed slower
```

if i choose MYISAM, I will have to give up update & NULL , if i choose INNODB i will have to give up fulltext and search speed

Which one should I choose, any suggestion? search or update, which one will be more important?

Comment: I think you're prematurely optimizing. If you need FULLTEXT search, use MyISAM. Otherwise use InnoDB and worry about it if/when you have an actual problem.

Comment: i have read lots post, ppl said MyISAM is bad for UPDATE

Comment: It's not that bad. Benchmark it with a realistic dataset if you can—reasoning from first principles isn't worth much with databases, they're too complex. Consider using Postgres instead of MySQL since these kinds of absurd tradeoffs are not necessary with it.

Answer (score 0):

General rule to choose between innoDB and MyISAM is

- Lots of writes - innoDB
- Lots of reads and just few writes - MyISAM

In Your case You may just update MySQL to newer version if possible.

[InnoDB support for FULLTEXT indexes is available in MySQL 5.6.4 and higher.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-storage-engine.html#idm46933183373424)